# Assign tasks to newly created user in jbpm

Tags: jbpm

I am trying to assign workflow tasks to newly created users.

I appended the users and roles in the user.properties and roles.properties in the jbpm-installer\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\configuration with my custom users.

Now i want to assign task to the newly created user without restarting the server. Currently using custom database(MySQL) for the requirement.

But actually get confused where to update the new users and roles.

How can i do this?

Comment: You need to override UserCallBackGroup. new user information must be persist to Organisation table in jBPM db. At time of server start it loads all entry from properties file and store into DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the jbpm-installer uses a UserGroupCallback that looks up valid users using JAAS, so it delegates to the application server authentication.

When using user.properties and roles.properties, this does not support dynamically updating these files without restarting the server, but is only for demo purposes.  Reconfigure your security domain for more advanced options.

Comment: So if i am changing the login module to database login module can i use the application without restarting. If so can you help me how can i configure this??